# function lambda выводит не то, что мне нужно

Tags: python

```
def create_multiplications(n):
    return [lambda f: i*n for i in range(n)]
```

получаем [12, 12, 12, 12] - нужно получить [0, 4, 8, 12]

получаем [6, 6, 6] - нужно получить [0, 3, 6]

Comment: Параметр `f` не используется. Так и должно быть?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да

Comment: `return [lambda i=i, n=n: i*n for i in range(n)]`

Comment: @S.Nick, это работает. Но чтобы объяснить почему, надо забраться в такие дебри, что я бы не рекомендовал. Кроме того ваша лямбда не игнорирует первый параметр, а в оригинальном коде игнорировала.

Comment: Опишите конкретную проблему в вопросе и в заголовке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все лямбды в вашем коде делят одну и ту же переменную `i`. Привыкайте создавая замыкания прятать каждую лямбду в свой контекст:

```
def create_multiplications(n):

    def make(v):
        return lambda f: v

    return [make(i * n) for i in range(n)]


print(*(f(None) for f in create_multiplications(4)))
print(*(f(None) for f in create_multiplications(3)))
```

> ```
> $ python temp.py
> 0 4 8 12
> 0 3 6
> ```

Если вам нравятся именно лямбды, то можно так. Код читается тяжело, но это то же самое:

```
def create_multiplications(n):
    return [(lambda v: lambda f: v)(i * n) for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: Всё понятно, спасибо!